# obtener una list<t> c# usando Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, mvc

estoy tratando de cargar una modal con unos datos especificos de un usuario seleccionado de una tabla.

Tengo una tabla donde se muestra una lista de usuarios, al darle a un boton me debe cargar una modal con la lista de propiedades las cuales posee ese usuario.

El id del usuario llega al controlador y hago la consulta de los datos que quiero, en el controlador puse un punto de quiebre y puedo ver la lista de propiedades del usurio,  el problema es que me da error en la function jquery al querer recibir esos datos.

Asi lo tengo en el controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult listaComunidades()
    {
        try
        {
            long userId = (long)Session["idTitular"]; //Aqui esta almacenado el Id del usuario ya captado por el conrolador
            List<Titulo> titulosList = new List<Titulo>();
            List<community> listComunities = new List<community>();
            titulosList = ep.GetTitulosByTitular(userId);
            listComunities = ep.GetCommunityListByTitular(titulosList);
            return Json(new { result = listComunities });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                data = "error",
                exception = ex.HResult
            });
        }
    }
```

Y este es mi codigo en jquery

```
function onCommunitiesList() { 
        var url = "@Url.Action("listaComunidades", "titulares", new { area = "webmaster" })";
        var errUrl = "@Url.Action("listado", "titulares", new { area = "webmaster", Error = "No se pudo procesar la solicitud."})";
       $.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',        
    success: function (result) {     // aqui no recibo nada o no se como puedo hacer que llegue la lista desde el controlador
                if (data != null) {
                    //listCommun = data;
                    //var t = $('.tablaComunidadesSe').DataTable();
                    //t.rows().remove().draw(false);
                    //for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    //    t.row.add([
                    //        data[i].Id,
                    //        data[i].first_name,
                    //    ]).draw(false);
                    //}
                    $('#exampleModalLong').modal('show')
                } else {
                    window.location = errUrl;
                }
           },   
    processData: false,
            contentType: false
        })   
    }
```

Este es el error que me aparece:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es un error del servidor, lanza una excepción no controlada. Deberías *debuggar* ese método en el controlador y averiguar qué falla. No tiene  nada que ver con el cliente...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que supongo que copiaste el código de dos lados distintos, por lo que las funciones tienen 2 nombres totalmente diferente.

Todo dentro de la función lo llamas `data` pero el parámetro lo llamas `result` entonces al querer usar ese parámetro js no lo encuentra y es el error que te debe estar marcando.

para solucionarlo simplemente cambia la siguiente linea

```
success: function (result) {     //
```

Cámbiala por

```
success: function (data) {     //
```

Y con eso debería funcionar

Comment: Corregi eso y voy a probar. Actualice la pregunta coloque una imagen con el error que me aparece en la consola de chrome

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar